# Std Errors in Panel Data & Simple Regression

Tags: panel-data

This question has been posted on 
http://forums.eviews.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=12747

How do I make the standard errors the same in both a fixed cross-section panel data and simple regression?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a pooled OLS regression by "simple regression" then I am afraid, generally speaking, it is not possible to make the standard errors the same for the two models. The fixed effects estimation method exploits within individual/unit variation and in fact even the point estimates for the two models should be different.